# how to send a post to apigility with resclientemozilla?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

how can I send JSON data to apigility using an HTTP POST? I'm trying to send this data:

```
 {
        "nombre_pais": "MEXICO",
        "id": "20",
        "artist": "JUAN AGUIRRES",
        "title": "CRAZY",
        "genero": "Balada, Pop",
        "ocupacion": "Cantante, Productos",
        "sitio_web": "www.juanAGUIRRE.com",
}
```

but I get an error:

```
{
  "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "JSON decoding error: Syntax error, malformed JSON"
}
```

What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess when someone tells you "JSON decoding error: Syntax error, malformed JSON" you should check the syntax of your JSON. http://jsonlint.com/ is one of many online validators. You will find that you have an extra trailing comma after the last value.

Every common language now has the ability to automatically create JSON, don't try doing it yourself.